# Find equation for an isomorphism such that

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

In $\mathbb{R}^4$  plane $V$ is given, $V=\operatorname{span}(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ where $\alpha_1=[1,3,4,1]$, $\alpha_2=[1,2,2,3] $

a) Find the formula for isomorphism $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^4$, such that $\varphi(V)=\operatorname{span}(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2)$

b) Find the system of equations which will desribe $V$

In b) probably i will have to use some properties of isomorphism, but i am not certain. How to deal with question of that type?

Answer (score -1):

Do you know how to extend $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ to a basis consisting of 4 vectors? 
If so, you can build a matrix $M$ with those four vectors as its columns, and the transformation $x \mapsto Mx$ will send
$e_i$ to $\alpha_i$ for $i = 1, \ldots, 4$.

Therefore the transformation defined by $x \mapsto M^{-1} x$ will send $\alpha_i$ to $e_i$, and you'll be done.

For part b, if you take the vectors you found in part a and apply the Gram-Schmidt process to them, you'll get four orthonormal vectors $\beta_i$ ($i = 1, \ldots, 4$) such that the span of 
$$
\beta_1, \ldots, \beta_k
$$
is the same as the span of 
$$
\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_k
$$
for each $k = 1, 2, 3, 4$. (You might even want to use the $\beta_i$ as the columns of $M$, for then $M^{-1} = M^t$, which is easy to compute!)

Because the vectors $\beta_3$ and $\beta_4$ are independent and orthogonal to $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$, the equations
$$
\beta_3 \cdot x = 0 \\
\beta_4 \cdot x = 0 
$$
determine a plane, and that plane contains $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$, adn therefore must be the plane spanned by those two.

Comment: thus $\alpha_3=[0,0,1,0], \alpha_4=[0,0,0,1]$?

Comment: Sure, those two would work fine (as would many many others, of course).

Comment: do not get the b) part is there any method to solve it without Gram-Schmidt?

Comment: Well, you could try to guess two vectors that are independent and orthogonal to both $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$...but pretty much every other method I can think of reduces to something equivalent to GS, so why not use it?